# Populating text fields from a filtered JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

I am currently using these two methods to set certain text fields equal to the row currently selected in the JTable. I run into a problem though when I filter that table.  When the data is filtered, the text fields are not populated with the correct data.  The fields are being populated with the row data that would be in that place if there was no filter on the table. Anyone have any suggestions or another way I can bind the table fields with the text fields?

```
private void tblEmployeeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         

            try {
            int row = tblEmployee.getSelectedRow();
            String Table_click = (tblEmployee.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
            String sql = "select * from Employee where EmployeeID = " + Table_click + " ";

            newDatabase.populateEmployee(sql);

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   


public void populateEmployee(String sql) throws Exception{
    Constructor("newDatabase");
    pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

      if(rs.next()) {
                String add1 = rs.getString(1);

                NewJFrame.txtEmpID.setText(add1);

                String add2 = rs.getString(2);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpFN.setText(add2);

                String add3 = rs.getString(3);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpLN.setText(add3);

                String add4 = rs.getString(4);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpMI.setText(add4);

                String add5 = rs.getString(5);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpAddress.setText(add5);

                String add6 = rs.getString(6);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpState.setText(add6);

                String add7 = rs.getString(7);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpZIP.setText(add7);

                String add8 = rs.getString(8);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpDOB.setText(add8);

                String add9 = rs.getString(9);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpHire.setText(add9);

                String add10 = rs.getString(10);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpTerm.setText(add10);

                String add11 = rs.getString(11);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpLic.setText(add11);

                String add12 = rs.getString(12);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpActive.setText(add12);

                String add13 = rs.getString(13);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpMan.setText(add13);

                String add14 = rs.getString(14);
                NewJFrame.txtEmpMod.setText(add14);
            }

connection.close();
}
```

Comment: Is your JTable TableModel decorated with Filter implementation which responds for your `getValueAt` or you filter & feed the data using some other way that the Model is not aware of ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: See [*How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), and "always remember to translate cell coordinates."

Comment: problem solved with convertRowIndexToModel.  Thanks everyone